# How to surround my "body" element with a background image

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner-casual, web developer, I want to surround my menu with a background image, I've tried to do it by myself, but still, it's shows the default white background, can someone please help me out?

Here is my CSS script:

```css
    body {
      background-image: url(https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bonappetit.com%2Fstory%2Fhow-to-buy-coffee-beans&psig=AOvVaw2rGyzxjYnZTpqbQELy-_qH&ust=1668543336904000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCIj8h7q-rvsCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD);
      font-family: sans-serif;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .menu { 
      max-width: 500px;
      width: 80%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      background-color: burlywood;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: The 'image' that you use for `background-image` is not an image. It's a redirect to a page or something... You will need to use an actual image

Comment: That is not a valid image URL.  I suggest reading about [BACKGROUNDS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Answer (score 0):

what is the problem in here is your link, but here you have a body with an image background, you just change the image for any that you want, make sure that it is the image link or the image path

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    a
</body>

</html>

<style>
    body {
        background-image: url(https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.5e6520289b44e11a9e74363c18ce3ee1?rik=0NsMGzWCfTqnyA&riu=http%3a%2f%2fcdn.wallpapersafari.com%2f34%2f38%2ffNuD4F.jpg&ehk=rWygJFVz8poo%2buNiEqsllRqA4jP9BCE6VYuBOMM03GA%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0);
        font-family: sans-serif;
        padding: 20px;
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        /* this is to make the image fits all the screen doesnt matter the image size, but it will cut the image
        background-size: cover; */
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add quote " "

```css
.menu { 
      max-width: 500px;
      width: 80%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      background-color: burlywood;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    
body{
      background: url("https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/vivid-blurred-colorful-background_58702-2545.jpg?w=2000");
      font-family: sans-serif;
      padding: 20px;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The image you want to use, save it locally and you can change the CSS to `background-image: url(image.jpg);

Comment: This doesn't work for websites intended to be publicly visible. If you're only doing local development on your computer, this works, but otherwise you'll need to upload the image to your website's hosting folder or another image hosting service.